# how to link names column in two columns leaderboard for names and the other for scores in leaderboard sorted according to the scores

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

i have leaderboard activity that contains two columns one for names and the other for scores... i have the scores listed on array of integers and i used bubble sort algorithm to sort em , and every time the game ends it checks if the user score is above the last one or not and if it's higher i replace the last element then sort the array again using the bubble algorithm...

what i wanna do is how can i link every score with it's username (i have different array for strings so far) and still in the same order.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a *[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)* collection, although, it provides no inherent way to sort the values.
You'll have to manually adjust whenever a score changes.

Your design, which is typically referred to as a *[parallel array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array)*, is correct, and is probably the easiest way to achieve this.

Just, adjust the *username* array in accordance to the *Bubble sort*.

Here is an example—implementing this *Wikipedia [pseudo-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort)*.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] usernames = { "userA", "userB", "userC", "userD" };
    int[] scores = { 1, 4, 2, 3 };

    bubbleSort(scores, usernames);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(usernames));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scores));
}

static void bubbleSort(int[] scores, String[] usernames) {
    int length = scores.length;
    int copy;
    String copyB;
    boolean swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (int index = 1; index < length; index++) {
            if (scores[index - 1] > scores[index]) {
                copy = scores[index];
                copyB = usernames[index];
                scores[index] = scores[index - 1];
                usernames[index] = usernames[index - 1];
                scores[index - 1] = copy;
                usernames[index - 1] = copyB;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        length--;
    } while (!swapped);
}
```

Output

```
[userA, userC, userD, userB]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```